# How to get Google Drive API example to run in Phonegap application (support for Android)?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-drive-api

I have successfully been able to use the example provided for the Google Drive API to authenticate and get files & folders of a user's Drive (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js).

But I need to convert this example to be able to launch on an Android device using Phonegap. When I run the Phonegap application I get the following error:
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

I have had a look at some answers for dealing with this error for other applications such as including SAMEORIGIN for X-Frame-Options in the meta tag and running the application in the emulator to see if it works but it does not. I have also made sure that the inAppBrowser plugin has been added.

Note, I am using localhost to test the application. I'm not sure if this will cause an issue.

I'm not sure how to solve Google Drive authentication in a Phonegap application.

Comment: at what point do you get the `Refused to...` error?

Comment: Hi @islanddave, it seems to be when it is trying to read this line: `gapi.auth.authorize({'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},handleAuthResult);` I'm really not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Hi  @sim1 Have you resolved the issue .The same issue  " X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' "i am getting kindly let me know if you can help me out.....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is at this point, nor what you are ultimately wanting to do with your app. Consider looking at Filepicker.io as a PhoneGap integration point for Google Drive. [Filepicker.io Home Page](https://www.inkfilepicker.com/) and the [github repo for the plugin](https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-phonegap)

Comment: Hi @islanddave, basically what I need to do is to authorize the user and then get a file list of what they have in Google Drive. The problem I am having is authenticating the user through the Phonegap app. I'm not sure if this makes it more clear?